# How do I add a string to parse, if array is missing a object?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have two arrays, song(ret) and artist(ter). I am retrieving that information from parse, but when the counts in each array do not match each other the app crashes. I want to avoid this and instead of the app crashing I want the string "sorry no artist is available" to be added to the row which is lacking the artist. How would I do this?

Below is how the database looks when it runs correctly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyLul.png)

Below is the database when it crashes. Here is where I want to add the "sorry no artist is available"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtsp5.png)

Below is the code for retrieving the data.

```
 func getSongs(){
    let retrieve = PFQuery(className: "Pointer")
    retrieve.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    retrieve.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        var object = objects as! [PFObject]
        if(error == nil){

            self.ret = []
            self.ter = []

            for i in 0...object.count-1{


                if (object[i].valueForKey("user")!.objectId == currentUserID){

                    self.ret.append(object[i].valueForKey("title") as! String)
                    self.ter.append(object[i].valueForKey("artist") as! String)
                    print(self.ret)
                    print(self.ter)


                }
            }
        }

    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because valueForKey("artist") may be nil and you can't put nil into an array.

I suggest you use a struct to hold the song data as having two independent arrays are going to cause issues down the track if they get out of sync (really annoying bugs to find)

create a struct like so:

```
struct Song {
        let title: String
        let artist: String

        init(titleString: String?, artistString: String?) {
            if let titleStringUnwrapped = titleString {
                title = titleStringUnwrapped
            } else {
                title = "Title not found"
            }

            if let artistStringUnwrapped = artistString {
                artist = artistStringUnwrapped
            } else {
                artist = "Artist not found"
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you just create a single array of type [Song] and append your new song structs into it:

```
if (object[i].valueForKey("user")!.objectId == currentUserID){
  let newSong = Song(
    titleString: object[i].valueForKey("title") as? String,
    artistString: object[i].valueForKey("artist") as? String
  )
}
```